# How do I update my library version in maven central?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, sonatype, maven-central

I deployed my library to maven central via `sonatype`. The library is released and I can access it from `gradle`. This is a library for Android, and I deployed it from Android Studio.

Recently, I updated some code and added new features to the library, so I want to update the library on Maven Central as well, but I couldn't find any info or guide on how to do it.

Should I just update version in the `gradle.properties` file and upload the library again via gradle uploadArchives?

Comment: Yes. You don't update a version that got already released. You just release a new version.

Comment: One of the foundational paradigms of a release in Central is: immutability. This means if you have released a version of your library it can not be changed anymore. If you have fixed a bug or added new features you have to release a new version of your library. Which brings us to the idea of versions ...best is to follow semantical versioning (https://semver.org/)